# Тип сборки проекта dev и prod

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, frontend, gulp

Почти доделал свою сборку gulp и недавно узнал, что некоторые люди делят ещё в добавок саму сборку на dev и prod.
**Можете объяснить зачем это нужно и какая от этого польза?**
Просто в моём понимании я запустил сборку, все задачи выполнились, потом снова запустил и так каждый раз когда нужно делать проект.
Зачем что-то делить на разные типы не совсем ясно.

Comment: dev-сборка быстрее собирается и проще отлаживается

Comment: prod-сборка сжимается лучше и работает быстрее